# Which method need to override to round the corner of NotiIcon's ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenustrip

In windows 11, I have found that almost every Systray Icon's Context Menu has a round corner.
As there is no Systray Menu for WPF application, I have used Window's form NotiIcon and ContextMenuStrip.
I have fully customized ToolStripProfessionalRenderer with ProfessionalColorTable to support dark mode
as per clients' requirements. Now I'm looking for rounding the corner. I was used "RoundedEdges = true;"
but not worked. I need to know exactly which method need to override to round the corner of ContextMenuStrip.

[image]

Here below is my renderer sample code.

```
   ///Menu Renderer
public class MenuRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    //Fields
    private Color primaryColor;
    private Color textColor;
    private int arrowThickness;
    private WindowsTheme systrayTheme;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public WindowsTheme SystrayTheme
    {
        get { return systrayTheme; }
        set { systrayTheme = value; }
    }

    //Constructor
    public MenuRenderer(bool isMainMenu, Color primaryColor, Color textColor, Color menuItemMouseOverColor, Color menuItemMouseOverBorderColor, WindowsTheme theme)
        : base(new MenuColorTable(isMainMenu, primaryColor, menuItemMouseOverColor, menuItemMouseOverBorderColor, theme))
    {
        RoundedEdges = true;
        
        this.primaryColor = primaryColor;
        this.systrayTheme = theme;

        if (isMainMenu)
        {
            arrowThickness = 2;
            if (textColor == Color.Empty) //Set Default Color
                this.textColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            else//Set custom text color 
                this.textColor = textColor;
        }
        else
        {
            arrowThickness = 1;
            if (textColor == Color.Empty) //Set Default Color
                this.textColor = Color.DimGray;
            else//Set custom text color
                this.textColor = textColor;
        }
    }

    //Overrides
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        e.Item.ForeColor = e.Item.Selected ? Color.White : textColor;
    }

    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Fields
        var graph = e.Graphics;
        var arrowSize = new Size(5, 10);
        var arrowColor = e.Item.Selected ? Color.White : primaryColor;
        var rect = new Rectangle(e.ArrowRectangle.Location.X, (e.ArrowRectangle.Height - arrowSize.Height) / 2,
            arrowSize.Width, arrowSize.Height);
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(arrowColor, arrowThickness))
        {
            //Drawing
            graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            path.AddLine(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2);
            path.AddLine(rect.Right, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2, rect.Left, rect.Top + rect.Height);
            graph.DrawPath(pen, path);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderGrip(ToolStripGripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(e.AffectedBounds.X, e.AffectedBounds.Y, e.AffectedBounds.Width, e.AffectedBounds.Height);
        GraphicsPath graphicsPath = RoundedRect(rectangle, 8);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green,5))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
            //e.Graphics.FillPath(pen.Brush, graphicsPath);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripPanelBackground(ToolStripPanelRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnRenderToolStripPanelBackground(e);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(e.ToolStripPanel.Location.X, e.ToolStripPanel.Location.Y, 
            e.ToolStripPanel.ClientRectangle.Width, e.ToolStripPanel.ClientRectangle.Height);
        GraphicsPath graphicsPath = RoundedRect(rectangle, 8);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 5))
        {
            //e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(pen.Brush, graphicsPath);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderStatusStripSizingGrip(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnRenderStatusStripSizingGrip(e);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(e.AffectedBounds.X, e.AffectedBounds.Y, e.AffectedBounds.Width, e.AffectedBounds.Height);
        GraphicsPath graphicsPath = RoundedRect(rectangle, 8);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green,5))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
            //e.Graphics.FillPath(pen.Brush, graphicsPath);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Fields
        //var graph = e.Graphics;
        //var borderZise = new Size(e.AffectedBounds.Width + 10, e.AffectedBounds.Height + 10);
        //var borderColor = Color.DeepPink;

        //var rect = new Rectangle(e.AffectedBounds.X, (e.AffectedBounds.Height - borderZise.Height) / 2,
        //    borderZise.Width, borderZise.Height);
        //using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        //using (Pen pen = new Pen(borderColor, arrowThickness))
        //{
        //    //Drawing
        //    graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        //    path.AddLine(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2);
        //    path.AddLine(rect.Right, rect.Top + rect.Height / 2, rect.Left, rect.Top + rect.Height);
        //    graph.DrawPath(pen, path);
        //}
        //DrawRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics, e.AffectedBounds.X, e.AffectedBounds.Y, e.AffectedBounds.Width - 5, e.AffectedBounds.Height, 15, Color.Red);

        //Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(e.AffectedBounds.X, e.AffectedBounds.Y, e.AffectedBounds.Width, e.AffectedBounds.Height);
        //GraphicsPath graphicsPath = RoundedRect(rectangle, 8);

        //using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2))
        //{
        //    //e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
        //    e.Graphics.FillPath(pen.Brush, graphicsPath);
        //}
    }
    
    public GraphicsPath RoundedRect(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Size size = new Size(diameter, diameter);
        Rectangle arc = new Rectangle(bounds.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        if (radius == 0)
        {
            path.AddRectangle(bounds);
            return path;
        }

        // top left arc  
        path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);

        // top right arc  
        arc.X = bounds.Right - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);

        // bottom right arc  
        arc.Y = bounds.Bottom - diameter;
        path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);

        // bottom left arc 
        arc.X = bounds.Left;
        path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);

        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
}

////////Custom Menu     
public class CustomContextMenu : ContextMenuStrip
{
    //Fields
    private bool isMainMenu;
    private int menuItemHeight = 20;
    private int menuItemWidth = 20;
    private Color menuItemTextColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color primaryColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color MouseOverColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color MouseOverBorderColor = Color.Empty;
    private WindowsTheme systrayTheme = WindowsTheme.Light;
    private Bitmap menuItemHeaderSize;

    //Constructor
    public CustomContextMenu() 
    {
        
    }

    //Properties
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool IsMainMenu
    {
        get { return isMainMenu; }
        set { isMainMenu = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public int MenuItemHeight
    {
        get { return menuItemHeight; }
        set { menuItemHeight = value; }
    }
    
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int MenuItemWidth
    {
        get { return menuItemWidth; }
        set { menuItemWidth = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Color MenuItemTextColor
    {
        get { return menuItemTextColor; }
        set { menuItemTextColor = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Color PrimaryColor
    {
        get { return primaryColor; }
        set { primaryColor = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Color MenuItemMouseOverColor
    {
        get { return MouseOverColor; }
        set { MouseOverColor = value; }
    }
    
    [Browsable(false)]
    public Color MenuItemMouseOverBorderColor
    {
        get { return MouseOverBorderColor; }
        set { MouseOverBorderColor = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public WindowsTheme SystrayTheme
    { 
        get { return systrayTheme; }
        set { systrayTheme = value; }
    }

    //Private methods
    private void LoadMenuItemHeight()
    {
        if (isMainMenu)
            menuItemHeaderSize = new Bitmap(menuItemWidth, menuItemHeight);
        else menuItemHeaderSize = new Bitmap(menuItemWidth-5, menuItemHeight);

        foreach (Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuItemL1 in this.Items)
        {
            menuItemL1.ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            if (menuItemL1.Image == null) menuItemL1.Image = menuItemHeaderSize;

            foreach (Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuItemL2 in menuItemL1.DropDownItems)
            {
                menuItemL2.ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
                if (menuItemL2.Image == null) menuItemL2.Image = menuItemHeaderSize;

                foreach (Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuItemL3 in menuItemL2.DropDownItems)
                {
                    menuItemL3.ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
                    if (menuItemL3.Image == null) menuItemL3.Image = menuItemHeaderSize;

                    foreach (Forms.ToolStripMenuItem menuItemL4 in menuItemL3.DropDownItems)
                    {
                        menuItemL4.ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
                        if (menuItemL4.Image == null) menuItemL4.Image = menuItemHeaderSize;
                        ///Level 5++
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Overrides
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (this.DesignMode == false)
        {
            switch (SystrayTheme)
            {
                case WindowsTheme.Light:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowsTheme.Dark:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowsTheme.HighContrast:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Utility.ToDrawingColor(System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuTextColor);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            this.Renderer = new MenuRenderer(isMainMenu, primaryColor, menuItemTextColor, MouseOverColor, MouseOverBorderColor, SystrayTheme);
            LoadMenuItemHeight();
        }
    }
 }
```

Update:

Recently I was tried to override OnPaint() method. But the round corner is not smooth and also sub-menu is not rounded.

[image]

```
    private GraphicsPath GetGraphicsPath(RectangleF rect,float radious)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, radious, radious, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Width - radious, rect.Y, radious, radious, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Width - radious, rect.Height - radious, radious, radious, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Height - radious, radious, radious, 90, 90);

        path.CloseFigure();

        return path;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        RectangleF rectSurface = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        RectangleF rectBorder = new RectangleF(1, 1, this.Width - 0.8F, this.Height - 1);

        if (borderRadius > 2) //Rounder
        {
            using (GraphicsPath pathSurface = GetGraphicsPath(rectSurface, borderRadius))
            using (GraphicsPath pathBorder = GetGraphicsPath(rectBorder, borderRadius - 1F))
            using (Pen penSurface = new Pen(this.BackColor, 2))
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
            {
                penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                //Menu surface
                this.Region = new Region(pathSurface);
                //Draw surface border for HD result
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(penSurface, pathSurface);

                //Menu Border
                if (borderSize >= 1)
                    e.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, pathBorder);
            }
        }
        else //Normal contex menu
        {
            //Menu surface
            this.Region = new Region(rectSurface);
            //Menu border
            if (borderSize >= 1)
            {
                using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
                {
                    penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
                }
            }
        }

    }
            
    //Overrides
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        

        if (this.DesignMode == false)
        {
            //this.Parent.BackColorChanged += Parent_BackColorChanged;

            switch (SystrayTheme)
            {
                case WindowsTheme.Light:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowsTheme.Dark:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowsTheme.HighContrast:
                    {
                        menuItemTextColor = Utility.ToDrawingColor(System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuTextColor);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            this.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional; 
            this.Renderer = new MenuRenderer(isMainMenu, primaryColor, menuItemTextColor, MouseOverColor, MouseOverBorderColor, SystrayTheme);
            LoadMenuItemHeight();
        }
    }

    private void Parent_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DesignMode)
            this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners

I also include the solution here just in case the external link gets deleted.

```
// The enum flag for DwmSetWindowAttribute's second parameter, which tells the function what attribute to set.
public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
{
    DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33
}

// The DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE enum for DwmSetWindowAttribute's third parameter, which tells the function
// what value of the enum to set.
public enum DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE
{
   DWMWCP_DEFAULT      = 0,
   DWMWCP_DONOTROUND   = 1,
   DWMWCP_ROUND        = 2,
   DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL   = 3
}

// Import dwmapi.dll and define DwmSetWindowAttribute in C# corresponding to the native function.
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern long DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd,
                                                 DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute,
                                                 ref DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE pvAttribute,
                                                 uint cbAttribute);
```

And to apply the rounded corners to the ContextMenuStrip:

```
ContextMenuStrip notifyIconMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
...
var attribute = DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE;
var preference = DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.DWMWCP_ROUND;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(notifyIconMenu.Handle, attribute, ref preference, sizeof(uint));
```

UPD
Here is the implementation of the submenu:

```
ToolStripMenuItem submenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("submenu");
notifyIconMenu.Items.Add(submenu);

ToolStripMenuItem submenuItem1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("submenu1");
submenu.DropDownItems.Add(submenuItem1);
DwmSetWindowAttribute(submenu.DropDown.Handle, attribute, ref preference, sizeof(uint));
```

In case you want to go the proprietary implementation route for rounded corners, here's a method for creating "smooth" ones:

```
Graphics graphics = ...;
...
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Above lines of code working for main menu only. Still I didn't find a way to work it for SubMenu. There is no handle for submenu.

Comment: @yeasir007 Hi. I'm not sure how do you create the submenu  to add in the `ContextMenuStrip`. I added my implementation that has a `Handle` for the submenu.

Comment: Thanks brother...this Pinvoke way is working... But i want to make it round from base class as it's a custom control. let me know it there is any way to do it from base class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set different `RendererMode` in `CustomContextMenu` other than the default one?

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (this.DesignMode == false)
    {
        switch (SystrayTheme)
        {
            case WindowsTheme.Light:
            {
                menuItemTextColor = Color.Black;
            }
            break;
            case WindowsTheme.Dark:
            {
                menuItemTextColor = Color.White;
            }
            break;
            case WindowsTheme.HighContrast:
            {
                menuItemTextColor = Utility.ToDrawingColor(System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuTextColor);
            }
            break;
        }
        this.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.Professional;
        this.Renderer = new MenuRenderer(isMainMenu, primaryColor, menuItemTextColor, MouseOverColor, MouseOverBorderColor, SystrayTheme);
        LoadMenuItemHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was tried but no luck. Recently I was tried to override "OnPain" method but round shape effected on main menu only not effect on sub menu and round corner is not smoth. I have updated the question please take a look.